# Type inference of implicit conversions

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit-conversion, implicit

Consider this code:

```
sealed trait Data
case class StringData(string: String) extends Data
case class IntData(int: Int) extends Data

trait Reader[A] {
  def read(data: Data): A
}

implicit val stringReader: Reader[String] = {
  case StringData(string) => string
  case _                  => sys.error("not a string")
}
implicit val intReader: Reader[Int] = {
  case IntData(int) => int
  case _            => sys.error("not an int")
}
```

With this in scope, I want to write an implicit method that silently converts from `Data` values to their "real" Scala values.

```
implicit def fromData[A: Reader](data: Data): A =
  implicitly[Reader[A]].read(data)
```

But then, this code does not compile:

```
val str: String = StringData("foo")
val int: Int = IntData(420)
```

The error is a type mismatch. Standard debugging methods for implicits show that the `A` from `fromData` can't be infered (all implicit `Reader`s are shown as applicable).

For your convenience, [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ernh2NaGRueg1c2O482rew) is a link to a scastie of the code. In [this other scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QVB4BEaWQZWPF83Msqzejw), a similiar, yet different, and working snippet is presented.

My question: What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the change to your `Data` class as well as your reader implicit conversion as below allows the code to compile.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

sealed trait Data[A]
case class StringData(string: String) extends Data[String]
case class IntData(int: Int) extends Data[Int]

trait Reader[A] {
  def read(data: Data[A]): A
}

implicit val stringReader: Reader[String] = {
  case StringData(string) => string
  case _                  => sys.error("not a string")
}
implicit val intReader: Reader[Int] = {
  case IntData(int) => int
  case _            => sys.error("not an int")
}

implicit def fromData[A](data: Data[A])(implicit ev: Reader[A]): A = ev.read(data)

val str: String = StringData("foo")
val int: Int = IntData(420)
```

You need data to be typed so that the compiler can infer which Reader should be used based on the type parameter of `Data`. Also notice that the following would not compile if you did not define an implicit Reader.

```
case class DoubleData(d: Double) extends Data[Double]

// Fails compilation because no implicit Reader exists.
val d: Double = DoubleData(5d)
```